# java 8 parallel stream, blockingcode possible?

Tags: java, asynchronous, java-stream

My situation is quite simple.

I have a list I want to perform logic on each item asynchronically.

when all the threads are done, i want to call a close connection.

like so:

```
bucketsList.parallelStream().forEach(t -> {
//some logic
});
 try {
 RestApi.getInstance().closeClientConnection();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
```

is there a way to make the closeConnection part wait for the parallel Stream to finish going through all of its objects?

EDIT:
I cannot use `CountDownLatch` as i dont know how many items i will have in bucketsList

Answer (score 14, accepted):

An operation on a `ParallelStream` is still blocking and will wait for all the threads it spawned to finish. These threads are executed asynchronously (they don't wait for a previous one to finish), but that doesn't mean your whole code  starts behaving asynchronously !

If you're actually making asynchronous calls and working on the resulting `CompletableFuture<T>` in your `forEach`, you should instead make your terminal operation a `reduce` producing a single `CompletableFuture<T>`. Intermediate operations could be a `peek` or an identity `map` with side-effects (both are frowned upon, but I don't know any best-practice solution). You would close the connection upon resolve of the single resulting `CompletableFuture<T>`.

If you're not, then your code looks good enough, as the `closeClientConnection()` will only be executed once the `ParallelStream` has been processed.

Comment: You are indeed correct! it appears that i had a different problem that reset my counter ( the logic i did was also async and i manage it manually to know how many requests are still running). once i fixed the reset counter issue this code worked!