# Parallelly 100 executions without loop counter using Stream

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Can the variable `i` be removed from the following code (because it is not used)?

```java
IntStream.range(0, 99).parallel().forEach(i -> {
    // do something without variable i
});
```

**EDIT:** Does anyone know another representation to execute parallelly 100 times without unnecessary loop counter?

Comment: It can't be removed. Even if you replace the lambda expression with a method reference, the method being referenced will require an `int` argument, even if you never use it.

Comment: ...which is same as `for(int i=0;i<99;i++)` without using `i` inside the loop

Comment: @Naman Oh, that's a good point.

Comment: You can always use [Executors.newFixedThreadPool(int n)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newFixedThreadPool-int-)

Comment: Also - be aware that making stream parallel won't necessarily just run all things in parallel. You still can have a single thread which will run your code sequentially

Answer (score 3):

No, you can't because `forEach` takes `IntConsumer` as the parameter and the lambda expression you are providing **must be compatible with the IntConsumer** functional interface. Now look at the IntConsumer interface's `accept` method it takes one argument  :

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface IntConsumer {

    void accept(int value);
```

So, from the above code, you can see that `accept(int value)` takes an argument.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, you cannot remove it. The `IntConsumer` requires an input `int` parameter.

---

Assuming you have multiple places in code where you want to do the same thing, you can use the following technique instead.

Create an `ExecutorService` and define a helper method for repeating a command:

```
public static ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(4); // Or any executor service you want

public static void repeat(int times, Runnable command) {
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        service.execute(command);
    }
};
```

Then use it as follows:

```
repeat(100, yourRunnable);
// or
repeat(100, () -> { /* do something here */ });
```

---

The `repeat` method can be implemented using `Stream API` but it does not guarantee parallel execution  of your commands. From the other hand [it is blocking](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44946694/10584605) and will wait for all the commands to be executed. This might be helpful in some cases:

```
public static void repeat(int times, Runnable command) {
    IntStream.range(0, times).parallel().forEach(__ -> command.run());
};
```